# Tail command to display matched pattern

Tags: linux, tail

I have a log file which logs network activities. I want to view the log file, but I want to see matched pattern. I mean I want to see the content of my choice. The log file is in this format: `Nov 7 12:00:00 ........`. How can I view content of a specific date or specific time. I mean if I want to see only 3:00 to 5:00 on Nov 7 how can I use the tail command to do that?

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using ordinary Unix commands. Use unix.SE or SuperUser.com.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do what you want. One of them using grep is

```
grep '^Nov 7 0[3-5]:' network.log | less
```